# Open link retrieved from IE in google chrome

Tags: excel, vba

Since I am not able to save the files in internet explorer, I`m trying to copy the links to google chrome because it downloades automatically. Only problem is that the links are not working or I am not using the proper references.

If I turn on the msgbox it will give me the exact url that I need but It doesn't work when I enter it in the shell line. What am I doing wrong here? Discard the code below downloadfiles, this was a first attempt to store all the links and save them all at once (but I can`t even save 1 file)

```
Dim allHREFs As New Collection
Dim TableName As String

    For iRow = 0 To 1
        TableName = "docTypeForm:documentTbl:" & iRow & ":j_idt250"
        On Error GoTo DownloadFiles
        Set allLinks = obJIE.Document.getElementById(TableName).getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each link In allLinks
                allHREFs.Add link.href
                testing = link.href
                'MsgBox testing
    Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" & " testing")

            Next link
    Next iRow

DownloadFiles:
    'For j = 1 To allHREFs.Count
        'obJIE.Navigate Url + allHREFs(j)
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    'Next
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" & " " & testing)` ?

Comment: ^^---- yes. variables do not belong inside of quotes.

Comment: "Since I am not able to save the files in internet explorer", why not?  Switching to chrome presents its own challenges and your script will break when chrome  updates if you don't update Chromedriver.  Not the end of the world, but it is an annoyance.  And depending on the reason, chrome may not even be a viable solution for you.

Comment: I would prefer to do it in IE but I can`t get it working. If I try with the hWnd=find window it fails on this line. I searched a lot of codes and they all fail with this command.